# Is there a way to optimize a query with Includes() in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, performance, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

I am developing a .NET 5.0 API. I use EF to connect to a MySQL database and it works great. Though EF is very optimized I have one query that takes over a minute to complete :(

This endpoint combines user data from a lot of tables together in one query. To do this I use the Linq `.Include(x => x.UserId)`. I have noticed that `.Include()` is very, very slow when you need to do it a lot of times like so:

```
var user = DatabaseContext.Users
    .Include(user => user.Item1)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Item1)
    .Include(user => user.Item2)
    .Include(user => user.Item3)
    .Include(user => user.Item4)
    .Include(user => user.Item5)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Item1)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == userId)
);
```

In my case this leads to the query querying over 200.000 rows of data from the database because EF selects everything from a table and only in the end adds a WHERE clause to filter the data. Example below:

```
SELECT t.item,
       t.item,
       t.item,
       u.item,
       u.item,
       ..etc
FROM (SELECT a.item,
             a.item
      FROM table as a
      LEFT JOIN table2 as c
             ON a.foreignid = c.id
      WHERE a.id == id
      LIMIT 2) as t
      LEFT JOIN table as u
             ON t.id = u.id
      LEFT JOIN (... another select)
ORDER BY t.id
```

I could use lazy loading which leads to significantly lower loading times but I have limited CPU power on the server so it would be problematic to run about 12 queries everytime I need this data. Especially if a lot of clients will use this endpoint at the same time (possibly hundreds at one time), so my preference is to do it in one database query.

So my question is: Is there any way to optimize the way EF handles the `.Include()` statement or is there another way to gain the expected result in a more efficient way?

Comment: Have you heard about `AsSplitQuery()`?

Comment: I have heared of `AsSplitQuery()` and thought it was lazy loading disguised as eager loading. In my case that would result in the same amount of database queries as lazy loading. My goal is to have one database query.

Comment: So your goal has no solution. `AsSplitQuery()` is only one fastest way right now.

Comment: If ```AsSplitQuery()``` not work for you you can try to simplify the query creating a variable ```var query=...``` trying to select as few lines as possible with the WHERE clause. Then you need to call the query on the database with a method that returns an IActionResult and call it in an asynchronous way. So the method need to be an async method and the var in which you return the result need to be ```var result = await queryMethod```. Hope it can help you

Comment: *the same amount of database queries as lazy loading* -- Why? It won't suffer from the n+1 explosion that lazy loading usually brings about. Also, the queries are executed in one query batch, i.e. a connection is opened only once.

Comment: Okay so, 
Lazy loading queries do not use that same connection and are thus slower than `AsSplitQuery()` which uses only one connection. 
Is there any drawback from using `AsSplitQuery()` in comparison to lazy loading?

Comment: @JortWillemsen, no, Lazy loading may use the same connection also. But is not comparable with `AsSpliQuery()` which is created for speedup Eager loading queries when you load Collection navigations.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Lazy loading is always triggered by in-memory entities, shouldn't that always open a new connection?

Comment: @GertArnold, if DbContext started transaction, it will not close connection after each query. So then Lazy loading will reuse connection.

Comment: Yeah, but usually that's not the case. In theory, lazy loading can still occur hours after the initial fetch. Well, anyway, it would be nice to see if `AsSplitQuery` has any effect. Too bad we can't see how many of these navigation properties are collections, but from OP's description it's very likely that cartesian explosion occurs.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv So If I use lazy loading to query the user and push all of the user in a response contract (dto), which triggers the lazy loading of the relationships, it should have the same performance as AsSplitQuery()?

Comment: No, again, lazy loading is worst scenario which you may choose. Try AsSplitQuery and check performance.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried AsSplitQuery. As you said, it dramaticly increases performance. From around a minute to 40 milliseconds! Though I am hesitant to call it a success. It uses a lot of queries to do it and I am worried my server does not have enough overhead to cope with enormous amounts of queries if my code will be used by hundreds of users at a time. That is why my preference lies with one query. Do you think this would be a problem?

Comment: Have you considered `FromSqlRaw()`?

Comment: You have no choice, one query for Eager Loading is bad scenario because of cartesian explosion of returned records. There is techniques how to do that in one query, but it needs implementation by EF Core team. Don’t expect this soon.

Comment: Jort, why don't you just try? Also the dto alternative? We can't measure performance for you, nor check which queries are executed. Lazy loading is very likely to cause n+1 queries, which may even be slower still.

Comment: @GertArnold I just tried it and it works on my own computer flawlessly as I said in a previous comment. Thanks a lot for your help. I am not in a position right now to judge the performance in a production environment and that is where my concerns lie. I thought you could maybe give some insight there!

The performance on my computer is almost the same between lazy loading with a dto or AsSplitQuery(). Both around 40 milliseconds! I settled to use AsSplitQuery() for now and will monitor the performance on production over the coming days.

Thanks SvyatoslavDanyliv and GertArnold